# Nestjs class-validator exception - how to throw metadata info for @IsNotIn validator

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, class-validator

I have a NestJs dto that looks like this

```
import { IsEmail, IsNotEmpty, IsNotIn } from 'class-validator';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
const restrictedNames = ['Name Inc', 'Acme Inc'];
class DTO {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  name: string;
  @IsEmail()
  email: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsNotIn(restrictedNames)
  orgName: string;
}
```

I am using an exception filter that returns errors with clear details on what validation failed and for which field.

```
app.useGlobalPipes(
new ValidationPipe({
  exceptionFactory: (validationErrors: ValidationError[] = []) => {
    console.log(validationErrors);
    return new BadRequestException({
      statusCode: HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
      message: validationErrors.reduce((acc, error) => {
        acc[error.property] = Object.keys(error.constraints).map(
          (failed) => ({
            failedValidation: failed,
            message: error.constraints[failed],
          }),
        );
        return acc;
      }, {}),
      error: 'validation',
    });
  },
}),
```

);

which returns an error something like this

```
{"statusCode":400,"message":{"email":[{"failedValidation":"isEmail","message":"email must be an email"}],"orgName":[{"failedValidation":"isNotIn","message":"orgName should not be one of the following values: Name Inc, Acme Inc"}]},"error":"validation"}
```

But for the failed validation such as @NotIn, i would want the error to be more specific in terms of what are the reserved keywords, and want them returned in the error as a separate key like:

```
{"statusCode":400,"message":{"email":[{"failedValidation":"isEmail","message":"email must be an email"}],"orgName":[{"failedValidation":"isNotIn","message":"orgName should not be one of the following values: Name Inc, Acme Inc", "data":{"reservedKeywords":["Name Inc","Acme Inc"]}}]},"error":"validation"}
```

But this block from the exception Filter doesnt return the constraints values with the decorator metadata.

```
message: validationErrors.reduce((acc, error) => {
        acc[error.property] = Object.keys(error.constraints).map(
          (failed) => ({
            failedValidation: failed,
            message: error.constraints[failed],
          }),
        );
        return acc;
      }, {}),
      error: 'validation',
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, there is no concept of returning metadata or whatsoever automatically. Since you are storing the blacklisted values in the variables. You can provide it as [`context`](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator?tab=readme-ov-file#passing-context-to-decorators), which is mapped to particular error types.

```
const restrictedNames = ['Name Inc', 'Acme Inc'] as const;
class DTO {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  name: string;
  @IsEmail()
  email: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsNotIn(restrictedNames, { context: { reservedKeywords: restrictedNames } }) // here
  orgName: string;

  // You may ignore the contructor
  constructor(name: string, email: string, orgName: string) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.orgName = orgName;
  }
}
```

Now all you need is to include the value conditionally in your transform function using `error.contexts`

```
const transformedMessage = errors.reduce((acc, error) => {
  acc[error.property] = Object.keys(error.constraints).map((failed) => ({
    failedValidation: failed,
    message: error.constraints[failed],
    data: error.contexts && error.contexts[failed],
  }));
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Like you want, here is the output.

```json
{
  "email": [
    {
      "failedValidation": "isEmail",
      "message": "email must be an email"
    }
  ],
  "orgName": [
    {
      "failedValidation": "isNotIn",
      "message": "orgName should not be one of the following values: Name Inc, Acme Inc",
      "data": {
        "reservedKeywords": [
          "Name Inc",
          "Acme Inc"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

PS: Thanks for providing the transform function. I am stealing it shamefully.